# How do I traverse from child directories to root?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

For example, I have a directory

```
/path/to/directory
```

and I want to set its subdirectories' permissions to something. This is easy:

```
find /path/to/directory -type d -exec chmod something {} +
```

But how do I do it in reverse? I need to set the same permission to

```
/path
```

and to

```
/path/to
```

and to

```
/path/to/directory
```

I have a lot of directories like this and I'm looking for some scripting solution

Comment: It's not clear how many paths you have, but GNU find has a -maxdepth option. find /path -type d -maxdepth 3 for example, if they all share some common root point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recurse upwards until `/` is reached and call a function for each directory.

```
#!/bin/sh

function mangleperms {
    echo DEBUG would chmod 755 "$1"
}

function walktoroot {
    DIR="$1"
    HANDLE="$2"
    if [ "$DIR" = "/" ]; then
        return
    fi
    "$HANDLE" "$DIR"

    # recursion (noun): see recursion
    PARENTDIR=`dirname "$DIR"`
    walktoroot "$PARENTDIR" "$HANDLE"
}

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo >&2 "Usage: walktoroot dir"
    exit 1
fi
# TODO probably more edge cases on relative dirs, though there are means
# to fully qualify those
if [ "$1" = "." ]; then
    DIR=`pwd`
else
    DIR=$1
fi

walktoroot "$DIR" mangleperms
```

E.g.

```
$ pwd
/var/tmp/a/b/c
$ /home/jdoe/walktoroot .
DEBUG would chmod 755 /var/tmp/a/b/c
DEBUG would chmod 755 /var/tmp/a/b
DEBUG would chmod 755 /var/tmp/a
DEBUG would chmod 755 /var/tmp
DEBUG would chmod 755 /var
$
```

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this to work. I've saved it in `$HOME` and run `chmod +x`, but when I try running `$HOME/walktoroot .` I get `3: function: not found`, the DEBUG print, and `5: Syntax error: "}" unexpected`.

Comment: I changed the shebang to `#!/bin/bash` and now it works correctly!

Answer (score 1):

With `find` we can do this as follows:

```
find /path/to/dir -type d -prune -exec chmod 755 {} \; -exec sh -c '
   while { set -- "${1%/*}"; case $1 in "" ) break ;; esac; }
   do find "$1" -type d -prune -exec chmod 755 \{\} \;; done
' {} {} \;
```

Another method using a `recursive` function:

```
   fx() {
      case $1 in ?* ) chmod 755 "$1"; fx "${1%/*}" ;; esac
   }
   # and then...
   fx /path/to/dir
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, a path is just a string. So you can split it on `/` and apply your command to each result. For example, you can use a little perl one-liner to print out the parent paths:

```
$ path=/path/to/some/deeply/buried/thing
$ echo "$path" | perl -F"/" -lane 'for(1..$#F){print join("/",@F[0..$_])}'
/path
/path/to
/path/to/some
/path/to/some/deeply
/path/to/some/deeply/buried
/path/to/some/deeply/buried/thing
```

If you now make a function out of that perl command (run this command or add it to your shell's initialization file—`~/.bashrc` if you're using `bash`):

```
pexpand(){ 
   printf '%s\n' "$1" | perl -F"/" -lane 'for(1..$#F){print join("/",@F[0..$_])}'; 
}
```

Now, you can use it like this:

```
$ pexpand $path
/path
/path/to
/path/to/some
/path/to/some/deeply
/path/to/some/deeply/buried
/path/to/some/deeply/buried/thing
```

And you can run commands on each directory in that path with:

```
chmod 733 "$(pexpand "$path")"
```

---

The approach above will fail if your path can contain newlines. A more robust version is:

```
pexpand(){ 
 perl -le '@F=split(/\//, $ARGV[0]); 
           for(1..$#F){printf "%s\0",join("/",@F[0..$_])}' "$1"; 
}
```

This is more cumbersome to use though:

```
pexpand "$path" | while IFS= read -r -d '' d; do chmod 733 "$d"; done
```

So, if you need this to work on arbitrary input, I would instead recommend writing a little script that takes both the path and the command as input:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $comm = $ARGV[0] || die "At least 2 arguments are necessary\n";
my $path = $ARGV[1] || die "At least 2 arguments are necessary\n";

my @paths=split(/\//, $path);
for (1..$#paths) {
    system("$comm \"" . join("/",@paths[0..$_]) . "\"");
}
```

Save that script as something (`foo.pl` or whatever) in a directory in your `$PATH`, make it executable (`chmod a+x ~/bin/foo.pl`), and you can now run it like this:

```
foo.pl  "chmod 700" /path/to/some/deeply/buried/thing
```